# Creating user in active directory using .net by queuing the creation action

Tags: c#, active-directory, windows-services, vb.net-2010, task-queue

I have received a requirement to create a new user account in Active directory. For that I have designed a UI. In that UI we have two options for processing the user creation action as Immediately and Effective Date.

Suppose an user select the immediate process , The app has to create the user immediately in the DC . If the user select the Effective Date option on the process drop down list , it has to put the user creation process on queue based on the effective date.
So, when the effective date come , it has to create the new account on that day from the queue action.

**How can I achieve this queue action and How can I create the new user account based on the selected date?**

Requirement is, The user can access a web page from anywhere through the intranet URL. And he starts to create a new user by the application.My DC server is in some place , the user may access from different place. In such case, **Do we need to run the Windows schedular or Windows service on the DC server machine or the client machine(Where the User accessing the web page from somewhere through interanet URL)  ?**

Answer (score 0):

Hi please refer to below link regarding everything about Active directory

> http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C

Basically to automate the scheduled creation of AD account, you can use windows scheduler or can write your own windows service to achieve the tasks.

Hope this help to begin with.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. can you please suggest me a reference site or code for windows schedular and windows service to automate some creation action

Comment: Initially/while development you start with Console application and core function in separate library. and later replace console app with windows services see link for help http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14353/Creating-a-Basic-Windows-Service-in-C